# Handling module federation failure in host app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-module-federation

How do we handle failures in host react app, when the app which is dynamically loaded using module federation is down?
I'm testing a scenario where I've bought down the module federation app and testing the host app gives this error, Load script failed error : localhost/remoteentry.js.

This is a genuine scenario where the app which is likely to be imported maybe down or have an issue.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

There is no in build mechanic from module-federation to handle async load failures. You have to do that yourself with the usual mechanics for lazy fetched content also used outside of micro frontends. For example in react you could use `React.lazy` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactlazy), [example](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/different-react-versions/app1/src/App.js#L4)) together with `React.Suspense` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactsuspense), [example](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/different-react-versions/app1/src/App.js#L39-L41)) to provide a proper fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [ErrorBoundary](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) component to wrap your exposed module, so on you host app you can have:

```
const MFWrapper = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <Suspense fallback="Loading...">
      <ErrorBoundary>{children}</ErrorBoundary>
    </Suspense>
  )
}


const renderMF = (Component) => (
  <MFWrapper>
    <Component />
  </MFWrapper>
)
```

and then on the Router:

```
const ExposedComponent = lazy(() => import('ExposedComponent/ExposedComponent'))

const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="*" render={() => renderMF(ExposedComponent)} />
    </Switch>
  )
}

export default Routes
```

By doing that, any error that comes from the `ExposedComponent` will not affect the host app.

Comment: I tried doing same but now the issue is lets say we have 2 remotes and 2 separate routes for each. Remote1 is down and Remote2 is up. In this case the `ErrorBoundary` is shown as expected when you click on Remote1 link but when I try to click on the Remote2 link, the `ErrorBoundary` component doesn't go of even if remote 2 is up. Not sure why.